# Creating form that is filled over time

Tags: wordpress, forms, pdf, adobe

I would like to make a form that users would fill over time. For example one day they would answer question 1, next day question 2, perhaps week later questions 3 and 4 or someone maybe wants to fill the whole form at once. In the form would be fields for text and images.

I hoped that I would accomplish this by using pdf form, but [this](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/adding-image-field-form-q41825.aspx) solution lets Acrobat Reader users upload only pdf files. I need the process to be as easy ad possible for the users, so they should be able to upload jpg images. Otherwise this solution would be optimal.

I really hope that the solution would lie in a file, which user would download and send back when finished. I'm using Wordpress site, so I'm open for online suggestions also.

Comment: Do you have to upload the actual image data, or would it be sufficient to upload a URI via the form, so that the host machine could follow that link to retrieve the image file itself? That would simplify the form data that the user would be submitting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Yes, it has to be actual image. I'm supposed to collect images taken by users with the form. Users won't have any advanced it-skills, so requesting them to first upload images somewhere would probably be asking to much.